# why dopar is not reducing time?

Tags: r, doparallel

I used an example from here 
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/doParallel/vignettes/gettingstartedParallel.pdf

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% sqrt(i))
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %do% sqrt(i))
stopCluster(cl)
```

This is my output

```
Loading required package: foreach
Loading required package: iterators
Loading required package: parallel

> system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% sqrt(i))
   user  system elapsed
  6.307   0.537   7.499
> system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %do% sqrt(i))
   user  system elapsed
  4.581   0.035   4.622
```

Why are the timing not reduced with dopar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I loose speed. You need to remember that there is a overhead in doing parallel computations:

**2 nodes:**

```
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(2)
registerDoParallel(cl)
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% sqrt(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.71    0.26    2.13 
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %do% sqrt(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.36    0.00    1.36 
stopCluster(cl)
```

**12 nodes:**

```
cl <- makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %dopar% sqrt(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.92    0.14    2.09 
system.time(foreach(i=1:10000) %do% sqrt(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.28    0.00    1.28 
stopCluster(cl)
```

For such a simple function, you cannot expect the time to go down by a factor corresponding to the number of nodes.

Compare with:

```
heavy_computation <- function(i) {
  Sys.sleep(0.1)
  1 + i
}

cl <- makeCluster(12)
registerDoParallel(cl)
system.time(foreach(i=1:100) %dopar% heavy_computation(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.00    0.95 
system.time(foreach(i=1:100) %do% heavy_computation(i))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.00   10.28 
stopCluster(cl)
```

In order to expect speed gains, the function should be expensive enough such that the overhead of sending the task to a child is comparatively small.